# Separate expression in its members

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to separate an arbitrary expression in its members? For instance, `object.propertyA.propertyB` would become `[object, object.propertyA, object.propertyA.propertyB]` (the values of each one).

I mean an actual expression, not a string. But, even it the expression could be in a string or could be converted to string, `split()` wouldn't be appropiate, because something like `object["propertyA"]["propertyB"]` would fail.

Comment: I meant it would fail if I tried to do this with `split(".")`, anticipating the most obvious answer.

Comment: `["propertyA","propertyB"].reduce((acc, prop) => [...acc, acc[acc.length-1][prop]], [object])` might be what you're looking for. The initial array can of course be replaced by `"propertyA.propertyB".split(".")`

Comment: No, I don't have an array of property names, I have the actual expression. And it must accept any valid expression, not just `a.b.c`. I guess I should implement/write a parser then.

Comment: Yes, you need to write a parser then. And maybe an interpreter. Although I'm not certain what other expressions than property access chains you are talking about?

Comment: As I said, the equivalent expression `object["propertyA"]["propertyB"]` should also work. There are no dots in there.

Comment: So only bracket property access with string literals then? What about `object[ "prop" ]`? What about `object[0]`? What about `object[5+3]`? If you need help writing a parser for this, you'll need to be precise about what input it should accept. If you want "all of javascript", then use an existing parser, there are a few.

Comment: I don't need help writing a parser, I want to avoid writing it. I don't know it all, maybe I was missing something, I wanted a second opinion. Thank you.

Comment: JS does not provide a way of reflection into the parser, so you'll need your own parser.

Comment: I just wrote a basic one and shared it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote a tiny parser that separates the expression, skipping nested subexpressions.

```js
var separar=function(expresion) {
    var corchetes=0,
        llaves=0,
        parentesis=0,
        comillas=null,
        bufer="",
        miembros=[];
    for(var i=0;i<expresion.length;i++) {
        var c=expresion[i],
            cAnt=i>0?expresion[i-1]:null;

        if(!comillas) {
            if(!comillas&&!corchetes&&!llaves&&!parentesis&&(c=="."||c=="["||c=="{"||c=="(")) {
                miembros.push(bufer);
            }

            if(c=="[") {
                corchetes++;
            } else if(c=="{") {
                llaves++;
            } else if(c=="(") {
                parentesis++;
            } else if(c=="]") {
                corchetes--;
            } else if(c=="}") {
                llaves--;
            } else if(c==")") {
                parentesis--;
            } else if(c=="\""||c=="'") {
                comillas=c;
            }
        } else {
            if(c==comillas&&cAnt!="\\") {
                comillas=null;
            }
        }

        bufer+=c;
    }
    if(bufer!="") miembros.push(bufer);
    return miembros;
};
console.log(separar("a.b[c(12+\"de\")+f.g](123)[h].i"));
```

Comment: `expression.split(/(\["|\[|\]|"\]|./g)` might be slightly simpler.